# MultiLine UIlabel doesn't show all text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uilabel

I want to show label size as per text in it for that I have used
uilabel number of line property.

```
lbl.numberoflines = 0;
```

but it shows only three line and after that it shows ... . not all text showing.

when I will give number of line more than 3 then it showing that line in label.

appreciate for help

Comment: set the Hight of Label

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
lbl.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

lbl.numberOfLines = 0;
```

if you want to manually calculate the height

```
 lbl.numberOfLines = 0; // allows label to have as many lines as needed
lbl.text =@"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
CGSize labelSize = [ lbl.text sizeWithFont: lbl.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, 300)  lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

// set the frame of labels here
```

else you can directly placed in Attribute

[image]

**swift3**

```
lbl.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
lbl.numberOfLines = 0

// allows label to have as many lines as needed
lbl.text = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
var labelSize = lbl.text.size(with: lbl.font, constrainedToSize: CGSize(width: 300, height: 300), lineBreakMode: .byWordWrapping)
// set the frame of labels here  }
```

Comment: it is working fine , I add the another one option bro wait

Answer (score 2):

So I had made numberOfLines as 0 and had given lineBreakMode as WordWrap and had given proper constraints too.

What worked was changing the preferred width setting to automatic from explicit. i.e. from this:-

[image]

to this:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
lbl.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
lbl.numberOfLines = 0;
[lbl sizeTofit];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method. May Help

```
-(CGSize)getLabelSize:(NSString *)text
{

    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(300.0f, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [text sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return labelSize;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers may helpful. but uses old approach.

can't you add **Constraint** to your view ?

It will be really easy to set layout constraint, and then you go.